# Problem with adding totals from user selected CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a form that allows the user to select from a group of checkboxes for automotive services. In the form, the user selects from a list of priced services and a final total is calculated based on what is selected.

The logic of the selected services being added up is
placed within a method that returns the total.

[image: photo of form].

Once the user clicks on the calculate button, all selected prices will be added up and displayed by the total fees label.

```
    public partial class Automotive_Shop : Form
    {
        const int salesTax = (6 / 100);
        // prices for services
        const int
            oilChange = 26,
            lubeJob = 18,
            radiatorFlush = 30,
            transissionFlush = 80,
            inspection = 15,
            mufflerReplacement = 100,
            tireRotation = 20;

        int total = 0;

        public Automotive_Shop()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private int OilLubeCharges()
        {
            if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                total += oilChange;
            }                 
            if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                total += lubeJob;
            }
          
            return total;
        }
           
      

      


        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            totalFeesOutput.Text = OilLubeCharges().ToString("C");
                
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // close application
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

The total should only be added once.

For instance:
if the "oil change" check box is selected,
then the total should be $26.

if the "lube job" check box is selected,
then the total should be $18.

And if both check boxes are selected,
then the total should be $44.

What ends up happening is that after the first check box is selected and the calculate button is clicked,
the "total" variable value continues to be added up.

So if i select "oil change" then click calculate, I get $26.
if I deselect it and select "lube job" the total doesn't equal $18, but $44.

Comment: Consider to create a struct with id, name, price and bool. Put is in a list and toggle the bool when `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` and either there call `OilLubeCharges()` or in `calculateButton_Click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem, the total variable needs to be reset to 0 before the calculation happens.

The calculate button click event should be updated to look like this:

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    total = 0;
    totalFeesOutput.Text = OilLubeCharges().ToString("C");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function should be responsible for whatever it does. So everything it does should be there, nothing more and nothing less.

This means when a member function is calculating a total, and in the comments you refer to it as a subtotal, this is what the function should do.

Therefore you declare in that function `int subtotal = 0;` and return that.

Then you could store this to a member variable if you like.

---

As an example regarding your comments, I have added the member function `int ApplyDiscount(...)`.

The only thing it does is applying a discount to 'a' subtotal you pass in. It should be improved for a working application.

---

At the button click the `OilLubeCharges` are calcultated, then that is passed into `ApplyDiscount`.

This return value you could store at a global variable. Both you could to event specify the full cost, the discount in price and the total.

```
        // Added a functionality due to the comments
        // When `discount` is 0.2f for 20%
        private int ApplyDiscount(int subtotal, float discount)
        {
            return (int)( subtotal - ( subtotal * discount ) );
        }

        private int OilLubeCharges()
        {

            int subtotal = 0;

            if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                subtotal += oilChange;
            }                 
            if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                subtotal += lubeJob;
            }
          
            return subtotal;

        }

        ...

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int subtotal = OilLubeCharges();
            int total = ApplyDiscount(subtotal, 0.2f);

            totalFeesOutput.Text = total.ToString("C");
                
        }
```

Comment: While that does fix this particular problem. I will be creating several other similar methods that will eventually all have their return values added up and totaled.

Comment: Would that present a problem with resetting the `total` variable to 0 every time?

Comment: A member function is always responsible for that one thing. What you say sounds like this function gives a subtotal. That means you need to add up those subtotals too, in the same way.

Comment: Have modified the answer.

Comment: I am beginning to understand what you're explaining, thank you. Would you be willing to help me further?

Here's my logic following you're explanation:
`OilLubeCharges()`
`FlushCharges() `
`MiscCharges()`
`OtherCharges()`

are all methods that do the same thing, add up a subtotal.
could I create a method similar to your `ApplyDiscount` that adds all of these method's return values together?

Comment: I suspect you are updating the labels in 'Summary' all together. These you could store into global members and add them to the `total`. Then update the labels. Updating the labels is a different task then calculating, actually. Perhaps you could even create a seperate class for the prices and options which is called in the button click: `class ServicesAndProducts{ int subtotalStandardServiceChages = 0; public int SubtotalStandardService { get { return ...; } } ... public Calculate() { /* call those Charges() here not returning their subtotal but update the global member subtotal */ } ... }`

Comment: and then when returning to the form: `label11.Text = ServicesAndProducts.StandardServiceCharges.ToString();`.

Answer (score 1):

You mention "the *logic* of the selected services..." and this phrase is insightful! Consider that one approach is to separate that logic from the *view* (i.e. the `Form` that allows interaction with that logic) because it's clear enough that when any property changes it causes ripple effects in certain other properties and the behavior is well-defined. If this "business logic" is placed in a non-UI class that models the desired behavior, the properties can be made smart enough to send notification events whenever they change.

For example, if the dollar amount for `Parts` is changed, it triggers a recalculation of `Tax` and the new value for `Tax` triggers a recalculation of the `TotalFees` property in turn.

```
class AutoShopModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case nameof(Parts):
                recalcTax();
                break;
            case nameof(StandardServiceCharges):
            case nameof(Tax):
            case nameof(Labor):
                recalcTotalFees();
                break;
            default:
                recalcStandardServiceCharges();
                break;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        

    private void recalcTotalFees() =>
        TotalFees =
            StandardServiceCharges +
            Parts +
            Labor +
            Tax;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This demonstrates that the model is smart enough to maintain the relative values in a consistent internal state regardless of which property changes. Then, synchronizing the changes to the UI is a simple matter of binding controls like `CheckBox` and `TextBox` to properties in the model that have been set up to be *bindable*.

For example, the `OilChange` property is just a bool and making it bindable simply means firing an event when its value changes:

```
partial class AutoShopModel
{
    public bool OilChange
    {
        get => _oilChange;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_oilChange, value))
            {
                _oilChange = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _oilChange = false;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Finally, the glue that holds it all together takes place in the Load method of the `MainForm` where the `checkBoxOilChange` gets bound to changes of the `AutoShopModel.OilChange` boolean:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        Binding binding = new Binding(
            nameof(CheckBox.Checked), 
            AutoShopModel, 
            nameof(AutoShopModel.OilChange), 
            false, 
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        checkBoxOilChange.DataBindings.Add(binding);
        .
        .
        .
    }
    AutoShopModel AutoShopModel { get; } = new AutoShopModel();
}
```

As a bonus, when you go to make the Android or iOS version of your app, the `AutoShopModel` is portable and reusable because it doesn't reference any platform-specific UI elements.

If you're inclined to play around with this View-Model idea, I put together a short demo you can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/automotive-shop.git).

[image: screenshot]